# FIPS integrity test failed on RHEL 7.5 with 4.X kernel

Tags: rhel, kernel, kernel-panic, dracut

I have a Dell PowerEdge R7425 with Intel NVME P4500/P4510 NVME drives.

On the 3.10 kernel, the NVME drives throw I/O errors very frequently, and these errors have led to a system halt once already.

I decided to test a newer kernel from the elrepo, and this seemed to resolved the NVME errors entirely.

However, the kernel will only boot when "fips=0" is set, which isn't acceptable to my organization.

When booting with "fips=1" in kernel options, the system fails the FIPS integrity test.

The following is displayed on the console prior to the system halting:

> alg: skcipher: Failed to load transform for ecb (cast5): -2

The same skcipher message is also displayed for the following:

> cbc, ctr, pcbc

Additionally, the following messages are displayed as well:

> alg: hash: Failed to load transform for tgr192: -2

The same hash message is also displayed for the following:

> tgr160, tgr128, sha3-224, sha3-256, sha3-384, sha3-512, sm3, xcbc, vmac64, and hmac.

finally, the following is displayed:

> tcrypt: one or more tests failed!
>
> dracut: FATAL: FIPS integrity test failed
>
> dracut: Refusing to continue

This has been tested with the following kernels:

> 4.4.169-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
>
> 4.19.12-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

The following RPMs for dracut and fips are installed:

> dracut-network-033-535.el7.x86_64
>
> dracut-fips-033-535.el7.x86_64
>
> dracut-config-rescue-033-535.el7.x86_64
>
> dracut-033-535.el7.x86_64
>
> fipscheck-lib-1.4.1-6.el7.x86_64
>
> fipscheck-1.4.1-6.el7.x86_64

The following is in /etc/dracut.conf:

> omit_dracutmodules+="systemd"
>
> add_dracutmodules+="fips "

Comment: I have! It auto generated the initramfs during install, but I tried selectively excluding and including some modules that required regenerating it manually as well.

Comment: Big bump!  Also experiencing this issue with RedHat Support refusing to provide insight due to the non-standard kernel.  Help please!!

Comment: I'm testing modifying /sys/module/nvme_core/parameters/io_timeout from 30 to 60, and so far have had good results. It doesn't explain what's causing the timeouts themselves, since the newer kernel is set to 30 still, but if it resolves the timeouts for the current kernel that could still be helpful.